# Why python script has to be run twice?

Tags: python, input, web-scraping, output

I wrote this python script to web scrape data and to print the output to a separate file.
The 'refID.txt' file has a list of IDs and for each ID, data has to be extracted from a site. The output will be printed to the 'output.txt' file.
Here is my code;

```
import urllib
import re

referencefile = open("refID.txt")

IDlist = referencefile.read()

refIDlist = IDlist.split("\n")

f = open("output.txt", 'w')

i=0
while i<len(refIDlist):
  url = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/variation/"+refIDlist[i]
  htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
  htmltext = htmlfile.read()
  regex = '<dt>Variant type:</dt><dd>(.+?)</dd>'
  pattern = re.compile(regex)
  Vtype = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
  vt = Vtype[0]
  printing = "Variation type of " + refIDlist[i] + " is " + str(vt)
  print >> f, printing
  i+=1
```

My problem is, for the output to be printed in the 'output.txt' file, the code has to be run twice. If the script is run once, no output will be printed. But if the code is run for the second time, the output will be printed.
How can I print the output when the code is run only once?

Comment: Are you calling f.close()?  I'm not sure about this, but I know XlsxWriter will not actually write the data to the file until the stream is closed.  Maybe your data is held in memory until open() gets called again?

Comment: I didn't. Do I have to?

Comment: I'd try it just to see.

Comment: I am not sure what `print >> f, printing` does, but have you tried swapping that for just `f.write(printing)`? It is also more efficient to write to the file just once instead of on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Will - I added f.close() at the end. And it works! Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, Glad I got to learn it before I came across this problem myself!

Answer (score 1):

Try using 
`with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:`

and then the code you'd like to run on the open file. This will close it automatically. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be working with files you should always remember to close your files to make sure the data is being read and written correctly and also to make sure that your resources are freed up.

```
import urllib
import re

with open("refID.txt", 'r') as referencefile:
    IDlist = referencefile.read()

refIDlist = IDlist.split("\n")

with open("output.txt", 'w') as f:
    i=0
    while i<len(refIDlist):
      url = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/variation/"+refIDlist[i]
      htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
      htmltext = htmlfile.read()
      regex = '<dt>Variant type:</dt><dd>(.+?)</dd>'
      pattern = re.compile(regex)
      Vtype = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
      vt = Vtype[0]
      printing = "Variation type of " + refIDlist[i] + " is " + str(vt)
      print >> f, printing
      i+=1
```

Instead of writing f.close() and reference file.close(), I opened both files with the `with` statement. This is the best practice when working with files as it will automatically close the file when it goes out of scope. See [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to get more information on with statements.

Comment: This doesn't work. Following error message comes - "Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6"

Comment: What python version are you using. This is for the standards. Python 2.7 and up

Comment: Please update to python2.7 or higher. If you update to python 3 and up you will have to change your print statement to a print method e.g print()